# Convert words in sentences and their in index in a dictionary to one hot vector pytorch

Tags: python

I am looking for a python function that takes a tokenized sentence and the index of the token as an inputs and returns a one hot encoded tensor
Ideally as in below

```
def make_onehot_vectors(sentence, word_to_ix):

    onehot_vectors = ...

    return onehot_vectors
```

The function shall pass the test below:

```
onehot_sentence = make_onehot_vectors(["this"], word_dictionary)
onehot_correct = torch.tensor([[1]])
assert torch.equal(onehot_sentence, onehot_correct)
```

word_dictonary look like this:

```
word_dictonary={'worddd':1,'wooord':2,'woooord':3}
```

I have tried creating

```
def make_onehot_vectors(sentence, word_to_ix):

    target = torch.zeros(sentence,[word_to_ix[index]]).float()
onehot_vectors=nn.functional.one_hot(target) 

    return onehot_vectors
```

But I didn't pass the assertion

Comment: Why the dict word_dictonary={'word':1,'word':2,'word':3} have many values for the same key? impossible right?

Comment: sorry Keys are different I will edit